# SuspiciousFileOperation: Storage can not find an available filename for

Tags: django, python-3.x, models, traceback, imagefield

I have this error after saving an avatar while creating an instance of this model (I didn't rewrite any base django model methods):

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

def conference_directory_path(instance, filename):
return BASE_DIR+'/static/dialogues/conferences/conference_{0}/avatar/{1}'.format(instance.id, filename)

class Dialogue(models.Model):
    ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=conference_directory_path, blank=True)
    ...
```

[image: Traceback]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to store a value in your `avatar` field that's beyond 100 characters the [default max_length for file fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#filefield).

I'm not sure why you store the absolute path in your avatar field, you can simply set `MEDIA_ROOT` in your settings file and your `upload_to` will store relative paths to `MEDIA_ROOT` only.

You can either do that or add a higher `max_length` to your file fields.